# Flutter drop down causes error in Future while using it with API

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdown

I'm very new to flutter. I'm using an API to which sends the data as an JSON. The format of the JSON is here.

```
[
    {
        "store": "AMAZON"
    },
    {
        "store": "FLIPKART"
    },
    {
        "store": "WALMART"
    },
    {
        "store": "ALIBABA"
    },

]
```

I need to use this store values in a drop down button. There are three files dataRetrieve.dart, homePage.dart, main.dart. main.dart Points to homePage.dart

homePage.dart's init state call dataRetrieve.dart to make a post request to get the data. The code of homePage.dart is here.

```
var markets;
  String _mySelection;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setState(() {
      markets = retrievedata.getMarket();
    });
  }
```

In homePage.dart I have dropdown button and the code is here.

```
child: DropdownButton(
                  items: stores,
                  onChanged: (sto) {
                    setState(() {
                      _mySelection = sto;
                    });
                  },
                  value: _mySelection,
                  hint: Text('Please select the store: '),
                ),
```

The data.Retrieve.dart code is here.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart';

class retrieveData {
  getMarket() async {
    String url;
    Response response = await post(url);
    var resp = json.decode(response.body);
    List stores = List();
    for (int i = 0; i < json.decode(response.body).length; i++) {
      stores.add(resp[i]['store']);
    }
    return stores;
  }
}

final retrieveData retrievedata = retrieveData();
```

The main.dart file is here.

```
import 'package:agrimarket/homePage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter App',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: homePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

While this code produces some error. The error is here

```
═╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following _TypeError was thrown building homePage(dirty, state: homePageState#8914c):
type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>'
The relevant error-causing widget was:
homePage
lib\main.dart:14
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
```

I have declared and assigned the URL.

How to use the retrieved value in dropdown.

Comment: post your main.dart

Comment: @Ferdinand Yeah added main.dart file!

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be to make the `DrowpDownButton`'s parent widget a, `ListView.builder`.Then, make the `itemCount:markets.length` and finally use this format to parse in the items for the dropdownmenuitems

```
 items: <[Stores]
          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: Text(value),
        );
      }).toList(),
```

Comment: It worked but with an error. after the execution of the map only the JSON file is returned. So the error is map was called on null. Please review it and give me an answer pls

Comment: Both code has the same problem. The problem is I should wait until the JSON recieves. How to make this thing?

Comment: Send the API endpoint you are using, however, I've tried to give you an idea of how you can deserialize the JSON

Comment: check this out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tSnPkRpqpdo

Answer (score 0):

To complete the [Ferdinand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13781222/ferdinand)'s answer you to make sure that `stores` is not remaining `null` before API do not complete to load data.

To avoid **null exception** initialize `stores = [];` or check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64894117/10663537