# Flutter app with loading while retrieving API

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using an API which returns the value like this.

```
[
    {
        "store": "AMAZON"
    },
    {
        "store": "FLIPKART"
    },
    {
        "store": "WALMART"
    },
    {
        "store": "ALIBABA"
    },

]
```

I need this to be in a drop down.
I need a drop down button with this API data in it. Some one help please. I have tried many ways but nothing worked.

Comment: Which way have you tried? Put code to get help please!!

Comment: @Hakiz'a I added the link of my previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64888506/flutter-drop-down-causes-error-in-future-while-using-it-with-api Please help me. From morning nothing worked out. I'm pissed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[nigale](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14654908/nigale) try code:

```
List<String> markets = []; // Or  var markets = [];

  String _mySelection;
  @override
  void initState() {
    buidDropDownItems();
    super.initState();
  }

// 
void buidDropDownItems() async {
    markets = await retrievedata.getMarket();
    // Refresh the UI if the State object has been created
    if(mounted){
      setState(() {});
    }
}

 child: DropdownButton(
          items: markets.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String val){
                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(value: val, child: Text(val));
                }).toList(), // Get items from the available data in markets variable
          onChanged: (sto) {
            setState(() {
              _mySelection = sto;
            });
          },
          value: _mySelection,
          hint: Text('Please select the store: '),
        ),
```

The function `retrievedata.getMarket();` is returning `Future<dynamic>` which `dynamic` is your markets list.

Comment: It causes another error. ```══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building homePage(dirty, state: homePageState#f375b):
The method 'map' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(Closure: (String) => DropdownMenuItem<String>)
The relevant error-causing widget was:
homePage
```

Comment: Make sure to have done like this `List<String> markets = []; // Or  var markets = [];` initialize the markets list

Comment: Then this error arises. ```type '(String) => DropdownMenuItem<String>' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => DropdownMenuItem<String>' of 'f'
``` Like the same from morning. Please solve this alone.

Comment: After some modification. Now new error is produced. ```There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: .
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value
'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart':
Failed assertion: line 834 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
              items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                return item.value == value;
              }).length == 1'
The relevant error-causing widget was:
homePage
```

Comment: Check my working example here https://codeshare.io/GbZB3b

Comment: What you have shared works fine! But when its tried with my API. It produces some error. `map was called on error.` can you share your mail there I'll share my API url. Use temp-mail.org Please a last try bro.

Answer (score 0):

let's say that this array is retrieved in a variable called `data`

```
 List<String>list=[];
for(var itemData in data){
  list.add(itemData['store']);
}
```

And wala, Now `list` conation array of `String` ready to be used

Comment: please see the comment that I have added a link to my previous question.

Comment: when I tried API returns the after the UI has been rendered. Please suggest me some solutions.